# Is it possible to incrementally add Where Clauses in an EF Query containing a Join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

**Aim**

I'd like to filter EF queries dynamically based on joined models (/tables in SQL thinking) as I already can with a single model.

**Working Code with a Single Model**

Given a `searchParam` I know the type of where clauses I need to do based on its `searchId`.

```
var initialSet = db.Files;
foreach (var searchParam in searchParams)
{
    if (searchParam.SearchId == "Id")
    {
        var searchContent = (int)Convert.ChangeType(searchParam.SearchContent, typeof(int));
        initialSet = initialSet.Where(m => m.Id == searchContent);
    }
    else if (searchParam.SearchId == "Name")
    {
        initialSet = initialSet.Where(m => m.Name == searchParam.SearchContent);
    }
    else if (searchParam.SearchId == "ImportDate")
    {
        var searchContent = DateTime.Parse(searchParam.SearchContent);
        initialSet = initialSet.Where(m => m.ImportDate == searchContent);
    }
}
return initialSet;
```

**Problem with Joined Models**

Without thinking about clauses for the moment, I have this initial join in mind.

```
var results = (from r1 in db.Runs
            join rf1 in db.RunFiles on r1 equals rf1.Run
            select new { r1, rf1 });
```

However when taking into account where clauses, since the `join` requires a `select` to occur, I can't simply join the tables, iterate the for loop like above and then select after. If there is a way to pass multiple prepared where clauses to a single query, I'm unaware of it.

I'd like to handle 0-to-many search parameters with these joined models. Any ideas?

Comment: did you consider to use a PredicateBuilder?
theese are cople links to see examples:
[nutshell link](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
and
[dynamic predicatebuilder to sql](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/)

Comment: Your problem isn't the `select` exactly - it is that you are selecting a new, anonymous type. You could either create a generic where adding method to pass in the anonymous type (which will cause you expression problems - what fields does the passed in generic type have?) or `select` to an explicit class you create and then you know the type needed for the `Where`.

Comment: @PowerMouse That looks quite interesting, I will look into that today. @NetMage If I create an explicit class Entity Framework will later complain when I try to evaluate it with something like `ToList` that it can't instantiate new classes in an expression tree. I'm not sure I follow the first suggestion fully, I thought anonymous types could never be passed as parameters (maybe short of using `dynamic`).

Comment: i hope it helps